# How can you make properties mandatory for an options object when using the IOptions pattern?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, configuration, .net-6.0

This requirement comes from a testing perspective. I'm happy with the `IOptions` pattern in that it should just load what it has from configuration and then you can use validation to ensure the options object has what it needs. However, when testing other parts using said options, it becomes an issue in that you can just new up that options object with as little as is required.

In my case I have my options object below:

```
public sealed record SomeOptions
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get;, set; }
    public Uri Location { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to ensure that whenever a `SomeOptions` is created in tests that Name and Location are mandatory to mirror what validation would cover in normal circumstances. Having tests using invalid instances of `SomeOptions` seems like something that could come back and bite me.

Ordinarily I'd encourage this via a constructor but this throws an InvalidOperationException when it tries to build the configuration as it needs a parameterless constructor. What is the best approach here? I've currently stuck a parameterless constructor in with an XML comment saying "DO NOT USE" but this seems woefully inadequate.

Comment: Wouldn't it rather be a unittest for the service the options get injected to? Along the line of "Can it cope with incomplete options"? The solution in the answers also will result in an exception there (when accessing the injected object). So whatever you do its part of the test for that service constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can migrate to C# 11 (and highly likely .NET 7) you can use the newly introduced [`required`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/required) modifier:

```cs
public sealed record SomeOptions
{
    public required string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public required Uri Location { get; set; }
}
```

If not than the only option is to write your own [custom analyzer](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/how-to-write-a-roslyn-analyzer/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Interesting idea with the custom analyzer. As we will be migrating to C# 11 in the future this would probably be unnecessary, so I'll opt for flagging this as tech debt to be picked up when we migrate.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `required` keyword like this to make Name required:

```
public sealed record SomeOptions
{
    public required string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get;, set; }
    public Uri Location { get; set; }
}
```

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/options#options-validation

If you want to go with the parameterless constructor that should not be used by consumers, you can add the `Obsolete` attribute on the constructor like this:

```
public sealed record SomeOptions
{
    [Obsolete("Don't use this constructor, use ...", error: true)]
    public SomeOptions() 
    {
    }
}
```

Then the consumer will get a error in the compiler upon using the parameterless constructor.  But this will not prevent the constructor from being used by the framework (via Activator or reflection) where your other rules will be honored.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I did think about the `Obselete` attribute but not really a fan of that either. As migrating to C# 11 isn't happening for some time I'm not sure this can be done right now. Feels like tech that will need to be stuck on the board for when we do migrate.

Comment: @sr28 the Obsolete attribute is totally appropriate in your use case as it keeps the tests in line with your implementation and can be effectively kept from breaking when the Options object changes.  You might even find that it's still useful even after an upgrade to C# 11 since you won't have to change ALL of your code at once.